# Tool to represent CSV file data in the from of tables and reports

Tags: javascript, php, csv, report

- I have a CSV file containing data for all User interaction with my web app.
- I want to represent this data in teh from of tables(stats) and stats.
- Can anyone suggest me a tool or an API to achieve this?
- A standalone tool or a PHP/JS library would work for me.

Comment: you want to csv data import to db table am i right?

Comment: No actually I want to represent the data in the from of tables and reports so that I can know who clicked what in my web app how many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your grids (Tables)

- http://www.datatables.net/index
- List: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

For your charts:

- http://www.jqplot.com/

For the stats:

- Use simple math like var1+var2/100
- or more elaborate: https://github.com/jstat/jstat

For the CSV data store:

- Use PHP http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php
- or use javascript to parse it: [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)